# Clang's __has_builtin doesn't always work

Tags: c, clang, c99, built-in, clang-extensions

With respect to the following test code, the expected outcome was that it wouldn't compile because of the `#error` directive.

```
#if __has_builtin(__builtin_types_compatible_p)
#error ("Hello")
#endif

#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    if (__builtin_types_compatible_p(int, const int)) {
        printf("INT ARE SAME!!!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, not only it compiles but it also prints out `INT ARE SAME!!!` which means that even though `__builtin_types_compatible_p` exists, `__has_builtin` is not detecting it. Why is it? And more importantly, is there some other way to detect for built-in functions that will work?

This was tested on Clang 3.8 and 3.9 (the current stable branch). The code was compiled using `clang --std=c99 -Wall -Wextra test.c`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note**: This answer is outdated as of Clang 10.

---

According to a LLVM developer,

> __has_builtin detects builtin functions.

In your example, __builtin_types_compatible_p is

> not a function at all, since it takes a type, not a value.

So, `__has_builtin(__builtin_types_compatible_p)` returns false, which is exactly as designed.

http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2017-July/054590.html

Answer (score 3):

Before Clang 10, `__has_builtin` only recognised built-in functions. Constructs like `__builtin_types_compatible_p` that take type arguments are not functions, but keywords with usage syntax *somewhat* resembling functions – similar to `sizeof`. Clang 10 [changed the behaviour of `__has_builtin`](https://reviews.llvm.org/D66100) so that certain function-like keywords are recognised as built-ins. However, built-ins that are neither functions nor keywords (like the type `__builtin_va_list`) are still not recognised as of Clang 11.

If you need to check for the presence of a function-like keyword in older versions of Clang, use [`!__is_identifier()`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#is-identifier). Alternatively, you can search for an argument to [`__has_extension` or `__has_feature`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#has-feature-and-has-extension) that covers the feature.

[GCC's implementation of `__has_builtin`](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git&a=commit;h=ad1539d5555a161cf6851de8995641d6dfe792d9) has supported function-like keywords from the start; it was added in GCC 10.